# Passing variables into a Shadowbox modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, shadowbox

I am trying to add an email service to a site.  I have a modal message window popping up with Shadowbox (since I had already used Shadowbox on the site for other purposes).

Problem is, I can't seem to pass a variable into my message form that opens up.

I am calling the window thusly

```
$(document).on("click","#mail",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisParentClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    alert (thisParentClass);
    var thisIDpos = thisParentClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
    var thisID = thisParentClass.substr(thisIDpos, 3);
    alert(thisID);
     Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<form method="post" class="mailForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="memberID" value=thisID><p>Please be advised that the member may not be actively receiving mail.. or they might just not care at all.  They have lives too you know.</p>Your E-mail:<input type="text" name="fromEmail" size="25"> <br>Your Name: <input type="text" name="fromName" size="25"> <br>Your Message: <br><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="nMessage">Your Message Here...</textarea> <br><button type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="mailSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button> ',
        player:     "html",
        height:     350,
        width:      350,
        options: {modal:true}
});
```

All of my alerts are returning the right values, but [thisID] is not getting into my message form.  I just keep getting HTML of 'value="thisID"' (note that the quotes surround my variable regardless of if I add them or not).  Is there any way at all to get this variable in, or must I switch to another solution? (I would like my windows to all look the same obviously, so if I can't use Shadowbox here I'll have to change *all* my implementations.  B*tch.

I'm not receiving a registration mail from the Shadowbox forum so I can ask this there for some reason, so I thought I would ask here.

Ideas?

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="memberID" value=thisID>
```

into this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="memberID" value='+thisID+'>
```

You need to concatenate the value of thisID into the full string using the + sign.

Full code:

```
$(document).on("click","#mail",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisParentClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    alert (thisParentClass);
    var thisIDpos = thisParentClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
    var thisID = thisParentClass.substr(thisIDpos, 3);
    alert(thisID);
     Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<form method="post" class="mailForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="memberID" value='+thisID+'><p>Please be advised that the member may not be actively receiving mail.. or they might just not care at all.  They have lives too you know.</p>Your E-mail:<input type="text" name="fromEmail" size="25"> <br>Your Name: <input type="text" name="fromName" size="25"> <br>Your Message: <br><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="nMessage">Your Message Here...</textarea> <br><button type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="mailSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button> ',
        player:     "html",
        height:     350,
        width:      350,
        options: {modal:true}
});
```

Comment: This was the solution of course.  Silly me.  I should know better.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing some quotes and plus'

```
$(document).on("click","#mail",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisParentClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    alert (thisParentClass);
    var thisIDpos = thisParentClass.indexOf("id-")+3;
    var thisID = thisParentClass.substr(thisIDpos, 3);
    alert(thisID);
     Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<form method="post" class="mailForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="memberID" value="' + thisID + '"><p>Please be advised that the member may not be actively receiving mail.. or they might just not care at all.  They have lives too you know.</p>Your E-mail:<input type="text" name="fromEmail" size="25"> <br>Your Name: <input type="text" name="fromName" size="25"> <br>Your Message: <br><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="nMessage">Your Message Here...</textarea> <br><button type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="mailSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button> ',
        player:     "html",
        height:     350,
        width:      350,
        options: {modal:true}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from the code you posted you arent' adding ThisID value to the code, but just writing it inside the content.

```
content:    '<form method="post" class="mailForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="memberID" value=thisID><p>Please be advised that the member may not be actively receiving mail.. or they might just not care at all.  They have lives too you know.</p>Your E-mail:<input type="text" name="fromEmail" size="25"> <br>Your Name: <input type="text" name="fromName" size="25"> <br>Your Message: <br><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="nMessage">Your Message Here...</textarea> <br><button type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="mailSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button> '
```

ThisID should be added via '+ThisID+' like this:

```
content:    '<form method="post" class="mailForm" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="memberID" value='+thisID+'><p>Please be advised that the member may not be actively receiving mail.. or they might just not care at all.  They have lives too you know.</p>Your E-mail:<input type="text" name="fromEmail" size="25"> <br>Your Name: <input type="text" name="fromName" size="25"> <br>Your Message: <br><textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="nMessage">Your Message Here...</textarea> <br><button type="submit" onclick="return false;" id="mailSubmit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```